# Trust level in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting, code-access-security, trust

I have created a website and uploaded using Godaddy hosting...

When I am trying to access a page which has an editor to insert data.. I get following error

```
*Description: *The application attempted to perform an operation not
allowed by the security policy. To grant this application the required
permission please contact your system administrator or change the
application's trust level in the configuration file.

*Exception Details: *System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
```

Comment: I believe it was caused by permission. Please contact them to give full permission to you. As I know, Godaddy doesnt support Full trust hosting. If you really need to run your application, you can find other hosting provider that support Full trust, find it at http://www.microsoft.com/web/hosting.

Comment: i cannot switch to other hosting provider now as i have already subscribe 1 yr package of space.....they provide a login through which we give permission to folders wherever necessary.. required permission is given .... how to resolve this issue now?

Comment: This has nothing to do with folder permission ... This is a trust level settings ... Certain ASP.Net application only works in Full trust environment. You cannot change trust level from control panel, only hosting company can change trust level on your account. What you can do is, you can try to over write trust level in your web.config file ... If, Godaddy has given you permission of override, your application will work under the new permission set.

Comment: I tried changing trust level in web config file but couldnt make application working....later i figured out i had rich text editor on my page Because of which all this was happening .So i replaced rich text editor with Ajax text editor and it worked out for me....Thank you all guyz for replying